# Using sed to replace first ntp server

Tags: regex, linux, shell, sed

In /etc/ntp.conf, I would like to replace the first occurence of the line with server (including the commented out line) using sed. However, many of the ntp.conf contains comments before the server line

Example 1

```
# xxxx
# yyyy
# server www.abc.com
...
server 127.127.1.0
```

Example 2

```
# xxxx
# yyyy
server 1.2.3.4
...
server 127.127.1.0
```

Expected Output (for both Example 1 and Example 2):

```
# xxxx
# yyyy
server 1.1.1.1
...
server 127.127.1.0
```

The following command line will also comment out the comments in the first two lines.

```
sed '0,/^.*server.*/s/^.*server.*/server 1.1.1.1/' /etc/ntp.conf
```

How can I only replace the line with server without removing the first two lines comments?

Comment: What's your input and expected output?

Comment: See expected output above, many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -r '1,/^#?\s*server/ s/^#?\s*(server .+)$/server 1\.1\.1\.1/g' inputFile
```

will produce output as

```
# xxxx
# yyyy
server 1.1.1.1
...
server 127.127.1.0
```

Comment: not bad! but if there is a line like #serverprogramtest, even that will be replaced with server 1.1.1.1

Comment: @A.M.D OP wants to replace anything after #server like `# server www.abc.com`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r '1,/[# ]*server [0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/s/[# ]*server [0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/server 1\.1\.1\.1/g' /etc/ntp.conf
```

Comment: It is possible the ntp could be not numeric. Is it possible to modify this?

Comment: give example @chesschi

Comment: see example above # server www.abc.com

Comment: this is a wrong ip, true i am not validating that.. but a comment line starting with server like i mentioned previously should not be replaced with server 1.1.1.1 . Anyway, OP seems to be happy with your suggestion, so leave it... :-) . Intention was not to prove u are wrong. :-) sorry if u felt so!

Comment: @A.M.D no porbs. i was just pointing out only :) 1 suggenstion if you dont mind, since you are repeating the [0-9]+ part, you can use a quantifier like `0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3}` which would be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n 'H;${x;s/\(\n\)[^[:cntrl:]]*server[^[:cntrl:]]*/\1server 1.1.1.1/;s/.//p;}' /etc/ntp.conf
```

take # line, text adresses